# Next available Date

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular, bism

I have a tubular model that has a standard star schema 
On my dim date table there is a column that flags UK holidays 
I would like to not included this date if a key chooses a date that has been flagged but the next availble date 
I don't have much access to the database to build a function for this as Ive seen others do

Could anyone suggest some Dax or a method of doing this

Thanks so much in advance

sample [image]

Comment: Share sample data and more details about your model.

Comment: @ alejandro zuleta
`SELECT [dimId]
      ,[dateKey]
      ,[date]
      ,[year]
      ,[month]
      ,[day]
      ,[monthName]
      ,[isDefaultCalendarNonWorkingDay]
  FROM [dbo].[vw_DIM_Date]

 WHERE datekey in (20160101,20160102, 20160103) `

Comment: I've added this to the post @alejandro zuleta

Comment: So the table in dax will look the same 
I would like to select 2016-01-02 because there is a flag against the previous. basically this is not selecting a certain date or weekend. 
So may a submission came in on the weekend but you want tag it with the day it will be submitted which is the next working day

Comment: Where do you want to exclude NonWorking dates? Do you want to prevent the user select any NonWorking dates from a filter?

Comment: It's more of a calculated column I'm after
It will utilize date where it's nonWorkingday is 0 but when it is 1 then select the next date that is nonWorkingday is 0 
So in the sample above the calculation against datekey 20160101 would actually display column Caldate *2016-01-02* (Caldate is the new calculated column) @alejandrozuleta

Comment: In that case, you can use a DAX expression to create a calculate column populated only with working dates. i.e if date is 2016-01-01 and is flagged with 1 then should put the not flagged next date. Let me know If that is what you are after, I'll answer with a possible solution.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta okay I'm with you 
I was trying to do this but got stuck when you have weekend and it could be two NonWorking days in a row. I'm still new to DAX 
it would be very helpful to understand how an expression could iterate through and pick up the right value , in this case the next working date

Comment: In that case, saturday and sunday dates will be flagged? or only the first date?

Comment: both will be flagged, basically any nonWorking date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a calculated column to get the next working `dateKey` if date is flagged as non working date. In case date is not flagged the column contains the `dateKey` value.

Use this DAX expression in the calculated column:

```
=
IF (
    [isDefaultCalendarNonWorkingDay] = 1,
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( [dateKey] ),
        FILTER (
            DimDate,
            [dateKey] > EARLIER ( [dateKey] )
                && [isDefaultCalendarNonWorkingDay] = 0
        )
    ),
    [dateKey]
)
```

I've recreated you DimDate table with some sample data:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to achieve! I think I dabbled a little with the EARLIER Function but didn't use it correctly.
Thank you very much @alejandro zuleta in having patiences with me being a novice. This is the type of comradery that needed on StackOverflow :-)

Comment: @user2181700, you are welcome. EARLIER is a very helpful function while calculating columns.